# Cannot perform an http put using Angular HttpClient in a Laravel Service

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am receiving this error: "Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Api\CasasVendaController::update() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in C:\imoveis_backend\imoveis\app\Http\Controllers\Api\CasasVendaController.php on line 103"

I am just experimenting with HttpClient and don't want to create a service and stuff for now. I just trying to test my backend I couln't.

```
this.httpClient.put('http://localhost:8000/api/casa-venda/' + this.id, {dormitorio: formulario.dormitorios, banheiro: formulario.banheiros }).subscribe(
    res => {
    }
```

The back-end is like this:

```
 public function update($id, Request $request)
{


    $atributos = [
        'dormitorio' => 1,
        'banheiro' => 1
    ];

    $this->update($id, $atributos);
}
  )
```

my route::

```
Route::put('casa-venda/{id}', 'CasasVendaController@update');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have issue in the php side. Change your function as

```
 public function update(Request $request){

    $atributos = [
        'dormitorio' => 1,
        'banheiro' => 1
    ];

    //$this->update($id, $atributos);
}
  )
```